# Executing SQL to get few rows from a huge table is throwing a error "No more spool space error"

Tags: teradata

```
 Select row_id from table_name
 Sample 20;
```

issuing no more spool space error...

Is there any query to get 20 arbitary rows from a table in less time ? Assume table is very huge one

Comment: It's interesting that you are getting a spool space issue on a single table select like that. Is you actual query much larger that it has to calculate everything before selecting the sample? You could use `SELECT TOP 20` but it will be less "arbitrary" and more "easiest 20 to get"

Comment: Review the EXPLAIN plan. Sometime SAMPLE can be devious in that it does more work to obtain a statistical sample across ALL AMPS. As JNevill suggests, TOP 20 may be a better alternative. TOP should return data from the first AMP that responds with data, if I recall correctly. Also if this is a view and not a actual table, the view can be causing more overhead.

Comment: Even I tried using top n rows querry, this time querry didn't issue "no more spool space", but it is in running status for more time, I just stopped it. No it's not a view. The table had more than 500 columns, it a huge one

Comment: How deep is the table? Is the data distributed evenly for the primary index? Do you have access to Viewpoint to monitor the behavior of the query while it executes?

Comment: Is there a WHERE-condition? Can you show the Explain? And the result of `SELECT Sum(SpoolSpace)
FROM dbc.UsersV
WHERE UserName = USER`?

Comment: As Rob Paller suggested, adding a proper primary index would cluster the table in a better way across AMPs, so you won't spool out on one of these.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common depending on the primary index of the table.  If you add a predicate using the primary index you should return results.

Just add a WHERE clause with the primary index in it to limit the results, and you should see results without a spool issue.

Comment: Well, using the PI will not result in *arbitary rows*. And if it's a simple Select without `WHERE`/`JOIN` (like the one shown by the OP) it will not cause spool issues (otherwise the result will be spooled first and then `SAMPLE`/`TOP` will be applied)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- Table_T is table name
- Table_v is view on that Table_T....

Following is the explain on query executed....

First we lock the `table_T` in view `table_v` for access

Next we will do an all Amp retrieve step from table in view table_v by way of an all rows scan with a condition of (table_T in view table_v.col2 is null) in to spool2(all_amps), which is built locally on all amps. The input table will not be cached in the memory, bit is eligible for synchronized scanning. The size of spool is estimated with high confidence to be 1 row (35 bytes). The estimated time for step is 2 minutes and 16 seconds

We do an all amps stat function step from spool2 by way of an all-rows scan in to spool5, which is redistributed by hash code to all amps. He result rows are put into spool1(group_amps), which is built locally on amps. The step is used to retrieve top 20 rows, then execute step4. The size is estimated with high confidence to be 1 row 41 bytes

We do an all-amps  stat function step from spool2 (last use) by ways of an all row scan in to spool5 (last use) which is redistributed by hash code to all amps. The result rows are put in to spool1 (group_amps) which is built locally on the amps. This step is used to retrieve top 20 rows. The step is estimated with high confidence to be 1 row (41 bytes)

Finally we will send an END TRANSACTION to all amps involved

Content of spool1 are sent back to user